# Flutter: Pasar de un TextField a otro automáticamente

Tags: flutter, dart

tengo 4 TextFields como en el código que muestro a continuación y he tratado que cuando el length de controller.text sea igual al maxLength salte automáticamente el Focus al siguiente TextField pero no he logrado ningún resultado.
Lo máximo que he conseguido ha sido poner el TextInputAction.next para que dando a la flecha del teclado pase de uno a otro pero me gustaría que saltará automáticamente. ¿hay alguna manera?

```
TextField(
    controller: controller,
    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
          enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
          counterText: "",
    ),
    maxLength: 1,
)
```

Comment: revisa lo que es FocusNode

Answer (score 2):

tengo una forma de hacerlo y es llamando a la propiedad `onChanged` junto con el `FocusNode`:

Creamos una instancia de FocusNode

```
  FocusNode myFocusNode = FocusNode();
  int cantidad = 1;
```

Una vez creada la instancia procedemos a implementarlo en el TextField al que nosotros queremos que pase automaticamente después de alcanzar la cantidad máxima de caracteres.

```
TextField(focusNode: myFocusNode,)
```

Luego lo que hacemos es que en nuestro `TextField`(donde ingresamos los caracteres) llamar a la propiedad `onChanged` y hacemos una validacion tal que así

```
TextField(
controller: controller,
onChanged: (value) 
              {
                if (value.characters.length == cantidad){
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(myFocusNode);
                }
              },
textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
decoration: InputDecoration(
      enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
      counterText: "",
),
//maxLength: cantidad,
```

)
En el código de arriba estaríamos validando la cantidad de caracteres que estamos ingresando en el campo de texto, una vez que llegue a los 5 caracteres, automaticamente cambiará al siguiente Campo de texto.

```
TextField(
controller: controller,
onChanged: (value) 
              {
                if (value.characters.length == cantidad){
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(myFocusNode);
                }
              },
//textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
decoration: InputDecoration(
      enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
      counterText: "",
),

TextField(
focusNode: myFocusNode,
controller: controller,
textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
decoration: InputDecoration(
      enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
      counterText: "",
),
```